# C# Using an ID to create an object in a constructor

Tags: c#

I want to create an Employee object using the constructor;

public Employee(int _employeeId)

In the body I want to read an employee from the database.
However I cannot get away with;

```
using (SHPContainerEntities db = new SHPContainerEntities())
{
    this = db.Employee.Where(x =>x.EmployeeId == _employeeId).SingleOrDefault() as Employee;
}
```

Because "this" is readonly.
So how do I do this?

Comment: why not do this: readonly Employee e = db.Employee.Where(x =>x.EmployeeId == _employeeId).SingleOrDefault() as Employee

Comment: I don't want to have an object that is readonly. I am pointing out that "this" is readonly whether you like it or not. I am sure there is a very good reason why this is so.

Answer (score 4):

You could just re-write it as a static method:

```
public static Employee Get(int id) {
    return db.Employee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == id);
}
```

(note: the above is just for illustration; there are **real** problems associated with a static data-context (`db`) - don't do that! It should really use a `GetContext()` method or similar, that worries about that)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing at the moment. That causes me to write;             this.Employee = new Employee();
            this.Employee = Employee.GetEmployee(_employeeId); and I would prefer to do the work in the constructor instead if possible.

Comment: @arame3333 well, you can't. You would need to copy all the properties manually, *and* then the data-context wouldn't believe that it is the same object. Basically, that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out you cannot set ”this” as it is read only (for a good reason). In your case the object is already created when the constructor executes, which means that you cannot change the type of the object. 
What you could look into (and what is already proposed) is to have a static method which creates the class for you. Look up the “Factory” design pattern, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your coding style. you ave to get the employee from somewhere else. for example, Try to use the Repository pattern:

```
var employee = EmployeeRepository.GetEmployee(emplieeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in another class, that actually makes the Employee object.

Answer (score 0):

Humm...

'this' is a reference to your current object instance. While in the ctor, you're in the process of creating and constructing the object itself. You can't change your reference inside the ctor and assign into your self which is fundamental reason of not allowing to change it or read-only.

The factory pattern mentioned by others are the solution for this.

HTH